# C++ passing a char as a string into a function without defining the string

Tags: c++

Consider a function

```
void foo(string s) {
...
}
```

I want to call the function as follows:

```
char ch = 'a';
foo(ch);
```

Of course it doesn't work as `ch` is a char and we need to convert it into a string.

I know I can do

```
char ch = 'a';
string str;
foo(str+ch);
```

I do not want to declare `string str` beforehand, I want to do something during the function call itself to convert `ch` into `string`, like:

```
char ch = 'a';
foo(some_operation_on_ch);
```

Is it possible to do so, if yes, how?

Comment: You can also `void foo(char c) { foo(std::string(1, c)); }` helper function for you.  Sometimes called a *thunk* function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes a character and an integer for the number of times you what the character repeated.  Using that you could do

```
foo(std::string(1, ch));
```

The class also has a constructor that takes c-style string and a integer denoting the number of characters to copy and you can use that constructor like

```
foo(std::string(&ch, 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It's indeed no throwing compilation error anymore however I seems like it is not working as expected. See, https://ideone.com/Vqx1fg I expect the output to be `inside: a` while it seems `s` as foo's argument is empty string. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @CodeTalker it should be `string(1, a)` - an easy mistake. Nathan should edit the answer too.

Comment: @CodeTalker I had my variables backwards like user253751 said.  It should work now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
char ch = 'a';
foo(std::string(1, ch));
```

std::string has a "fill constructor" that creates a string with n copies (1 in the above example) of ch.
If you have a function:`foo(std::string s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }` it will print 'a' and this should answer what you have asked for to do it inside the parenthesis.